# How old is the phrase "emerald by day, ruby by night"?

Tags: phrase-origin

I have found that the mineral alexandrite is described by a recurrent phrase, "emerald by day, ruby by night". I am trying to ascertain if this expression was current in a text written before 1910. A search in Google Books yielded results as far as 1913 (in [Diamonds, Pearls and Precious Stones](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=u5gZAAAAYAAJ&q=alexandrite%20emerald%20by%20day,%20ruby%20by%20night&dq=alexandrite%20emerald%20by%20day,%20ruby%20by%20night&hl=pt-BR&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_7ZaQrreDAxXqArkGHWcWB2gQ6AF6BAgMEAI)).  How old is this expression?

Comment: "emerald by day, ruby by night" is not a set phrase. "X by day and Y by night" (and variants) is a common construction. As you have found only one source, I assume that the author liked the example and used it more than once. The website This is Gems https://thesisgems.com/blogs/news/emerald-by-day-ruby-by-night-color-shifting-alexandrite says that the mineral and its properties were discovered in Russia in the 1830s. The phrase, in English, will have been used some time after that

Comment: The earliest reference I can find is [1890, *The Critic*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Critic/zFdDAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22emerald+by+day%22&pg=PA126&printsec=frontcover), talking about Walt Whitman being *...like that strange Siberian stone which is an emerald by day and a ruby by night he is different at different times, mood-struck or moon-struck according to your mood , as variable as a silk that is shot through...* But there are lots of "One colour by day, another by night" references to various minerals, plants, insects,...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for the "origin" of an utterance that's really just an unexceptional "observation" (it's not a "saying" that would have been meaningfully "coined").

Comment: If this is a maxim in a particular area such as geology or crystal healing, you could ask in a relevant place and see if there is some more obscure source. But if there is a much earlier answer than what Google Books has, it may well be in a foreign language (German maybe) in which case English Language and Usage is definitely not the best place.

Comment: Alexandrite was only discovered in 1830.  That would put a limit on its origin.

Comment: @Chenmunka: Even Alexandrite has several variants of the X and Y values for "X by day, Y by night" (mostly, X and Y are colours and/or gemstones, but not *always*). And I'm sure even Ancient Greeks and Romans would have noticed that some things look radically different in candlelight / firelight than in sunlight, so the equivalent observation will be very old indeed. It probably goes back to *caveman* times!

Comment: *Five Thousand Miles in a Sledge: A Mid-winter Journey Across Siberia* by Lionel Francis Gowing (London, 1889) "The topaz, the amethyst, and the alexandrite, the curious stone which shows like the emerald by day and the ruby by night are to be had here in abundance at moderate prices and pretty objects carved in malachite lapis lazuli and numerous other varieties of beautiful minerals are on sale everywhere "

Comment: @FumbleFingers — Yet the author of *Diamonds, Pearls and Precious Stones* put it in quotes — indicating some kind of coinage.

Comment: Here’s an interesting read: [Russian Alexandrites by Karl Schmetzer](https://dokumen.pub/russian-alexandrites-9783510654666-9783510652624.html) *...its colours, green in daylight and red in incandescent light, represented the national military colours of Imperial Russia.... The colour change of alexandrite “green by day, red at night”...* One can find earlier references with green and red instead of emerald and ruby. But I don’t know your specific goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stone was first found in Siberia and early references to it all describe it in that context. Its optical properties were noted when it was discovered, but the specific saying in question originated much later in the 19th century.

The oldest reference I can find is from the travelogue [*Five Thousand Miles in a Sledge: A Mid-winter Journey Across Siberia* (Gowing 1889)](https://archive.org/details/fivethousandmil00gowigoog/page/n273/mode/2up?q=%22ruby+by+night%22):

> The topaz, the amethyst, and the alexandrite, the curious stone which shows like the emerald by day and the ruby by night, are to be had here in abundance at moderate prices; and pretty objects carved in malachite, lapis lazuli, and numerous other varieties of beautiful minerals are on sale everywhere.

(After writing this up, I realized that @TimR had also discovered this source in the comments section, so I can't claim priority for this discovery.)

I can't prove, of course, that Gowing originated the phrase. One possibility is that the saying originated *in Russian* before being translated.

Comment: It is not clear why this would be characterised as a **saying** in any language. It is simply a description of this particular stone; there is no evidence of its having ever been used for any other purpose.